# Solving first order ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was trying to compute the solution for the following differential equation:
$$x(2x^2y\log(y)+1)y'=2y$$

As I couldn't get anywhere I checked the hints in the textbook which are the following:

Reverse the way of thinking, namely view $x$ as a function and $y$ as a variable, considering that $y=\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{\frac{dx}{dy}} => y'=\frac{1}{x'}$ . Then it goes to say that the equation now becomes $$x'-\frac{x}{2y}=\log(y)x^3$$

This final equation is obviously simple enough to solve, but how on Earth did they arrive there?

Comment: Are you sure it's not $x'-\frac{x}{2y}=log(y)x^3$?

Comment: You're right, I'll correct it right away

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $y'=\frac{1}{x'}$, 
\begin{align*}
\frac{x(2x^2y \log(y)+1)}{x'}=2y \\
\Rightarrow \frac{x(2x^2y \log(y)+1)}{2y}=x' \\
\Rightarrow x^3 \log(y) + \frac{x}{2y}=x' \\
\end{align*}
and rearranging gets you to your equation.